# invisible text inside svg text element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a simple function that supposed to display a couple of text elements.

```
function d3manipulation() {
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);
    var nodes = [
        { "name": "Michael" },
        { "name": "John" }
    ];
    svg
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
}
```

But on the page it shows nothing. I don't have any console errors either.

However `inspector` shows that there are in fact `text` elements with the data.

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
    <text>Michael</text>
    <text>John</text>
</svg>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: give the `text` a class and set a `fill` attribute to `limegreen`

Comment: @rioV8 I tried with `style> text { fill: "limegreen"; }` and with `.attr("fill", "limegreen")` and it added attribute fill but still displays nothing

Comment: Try giving the `text` some `x`, `y` coordinates: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text#Attributes

Comment: Also, please post a fiddle with working code so we can see exactly what is going on

Comment: Related, if not duplicate [*"Why svg text disappears when setting x and y to 0?"*](/q/21777376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving it an `x` and `y` was enough like @jrook suggested. (default fill is black)

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500);
    var nodes = [
        { "name": "Michael" },
        { "name": "John" }
    ];
    svg
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .attr('x', 20)
        .attr('y', (d, i) => 30 + 20 * i);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: indeed, `x` & `y` was needed. Or and as always I forgot about ES6.